# Param in CmdletBinding not mandatory and error/misspelled checking

Tags: powershell, parameters, powershell-5.0, powershell-cmdlet

Hey all I have a **powershell** script that I need to send some parameters to. However, sometimes I do not need to send any or maybe one out of the two.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='SkipAutoLoader')][switch]$SkipAutoLoader,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='AppPool')][switch]$AppPool
)

[more code here....]

if (-not $SkipAutoLoader) {
    $services += "Auto Loader Service"
}

[more code here....]
```

The above works just fine as long as I have either:

> .\Start-AkkServides.ps1 -SkipAutoLoader

or

> .\Start-AllServices -AppPool

If I have both together:

> .\Start-AllServices -SkipAutoLoader -AppPool

It errors out.

```
C:\src\Start-AllServices.ps1 : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\Start-AllServices.ps1 -SkipAutoLoader -AppPool
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-AllServices.ps1], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Start-AllServices.ps1
```

I also want to be able to determine if the param has the valid **-SkipAutoLoader** and/or **-AppPool** but with something else tagged like **-SkipAutoLoader43**

I would like to say that **-SkipAutoLoaderbob** is an invalid param. But do not show an error if either param is not present.

> **Loads Fine:**
> .\Start-AllServides.ps1 -SkipAutoLoader
>
> **Loads Fine:**
> .\Start-AllServides.ps1 -AppPool
>
> **Does Not Load Fine/causes error:**
> .\Start-AllServides.ps1 -SkipAutoLoader -AppPool
>
> **Does Not Load Fine/casues error:**
> .\Start-AllServides.ps1
>
> **Does not say param is not valid:**
> .\Start-AllServides.ps1 -SkipAutoLoaderbob
>
> **Does not say param is not valid:**
> .\Start-AllServides.ps1 -AppPool7

Possible to do with powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your parameters are in *separate [parameter sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parameter_Sets)* (only<sup>[1]</sup>), so by design they cannot be used *together*.

  - If your parameters can be freely combined, you don't need to define parameter sets at all.
- Since your script is an [*advanced*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) one, thanks to `[CmdletBinding()]` and/or `[Parameter()]` attributes, calling with non-declared parameter names is automatically prevented.

  - However, the lack of a *default* parameter-set designation in the `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute causes a more fundamental error if you *only* specify an unsupported parameter name (such as `-SkipAutoLoaderbob`): PowerShell then doesn't know which of the two defined parameter sets to select, because no *declared* parameter can be bound (before even considering whether the parameter name given is valid, perhaps surprisingly)
  - Use `[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='AppPool')]`, for instance, to designate the default parameter set.

Assuming that your two parameters can be freely combined and neither is mandatory (which `[switch]` parameters shouldn't be anyway), your code can be simplified to:

```sh
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
  [switch] $SkipAutoLoader,
  [switch] $AppPool
)

# Output the name of the active parameter set.
$PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName
```

Note that non-mandatory parameters without explicit parameter-set membership (and other non-default parameter properties) do not require `[Parameter()]` attributes.

When you invoke the script, you'll see that PowerShell *implicitly* defines a parameter set in the absence of explicitly declared ones, named `__AllParameterSets`.

---

<sup>[1] Note that a parameter can belong to *multiple* explicitly specified parameter sets, via multiple `[Parameter(ParameterSetName= '...')]` attributes. Any parameter without an explicit parameter-set membership is implicitly part of *all* parameter sets.</sup>